# How to find a ENUM value from MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server, database, enums

I am giving a Sample Demo and what i am getting as Result.

```
+-------+----------
 name      status
+-------+----------
 Subha     1
 Rajeeb    2
 Rahul     3
+-------+----------
```

The type of the status field is ENUM.

When I'm trying to get the result of ENUM like:

`select name, status+0 from demo;`

I am getting name and status for 2 and 3 and not 1. I have also tried `IN(0,2)` and `status=2` queries.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enum` value's can be compared using `'` single quotes like:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `demo` WHERE `demo`.`status` = '1'
```

or

```
SELECT `name` FROM `demo` WHERE `demo`.`status` IN('11, '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user `Query` like this:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `demo` WHERE `demo`.`status` = 1
```

you get name where `status is 0`.

if you want to get data where status is 1 and 2 the you just have to add where condition like :

```
WHERE (`demo`.`status` = 1 OR  `demo`.`status` = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being, enum has its internal datatype of tinyint(starting with 0) and when you're using the status in where clause. Having status=0 makes the where clause to return false.

Look at this scenario:

```
SELECT `name`, `status` FROM `demo` WHERE `demo`.`status` = 0
```

this make the where condition not satisfied and return no result.

Where in status=1 or 2 its satisfied and corresponding rows returned.
Solution:

```
SELECT `name`, `status` FROM `demo` WHERE `demo`.`status` > -1
```